# Shouldnt This not Throw an "Already Open Error" when going through a text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am running a few commands on the domain computers. I would like to test it before I actually use it in the "bigger picture". When I run this it returns data for the computers that it can connect to (no admin machine right now).

But for example if I list My personal Computer twice in the txt file it reads from, it says File is already being used and skips me.

Is this an error because its the same computer? I would like it to be able to just go ahead and write the duplicate if it comes across one.

```vb
Sub HandleInfo()
    'Declare Command
        Dim sCommand = "pushd \\*\C$ && whoami.exe >> C:\JavaInfo.txt && java.exe -version 2>> C:\JavaInfo.txt"
'declare File where Users are Located
        Dim strFile As String = "C:\TestDUsers.txt"
    'declare Lines in User.Txt File
        Dim strLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFile)
         For Each strUserName As String In strLines
        Dim ReplaceCommand As String = sCommand.Replace("*", strUserName)
        Shell("cmd.exe /c" & ReplaceCommand)
    Next
```

Comment: what is scommand please attach more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to :

```
Shell("cmd.exe /c" & ReplaceCommand, AppWinStyle.Hide, True, -1)
```

This will make it wait until the command has finished executing. The -1 means it will not timeout, it'll wait forever, so you can change that as you wish to suit.

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.71).aspx?ppud=4

Also, I'd change:

```
 Dim sCommand = "pushd \\*\C$ && whoami.exe >> C:\JavaInfo.txt && java.exe -version 2>> C:\JavaInfo.txt"
```

To this, using double quotes, as cmd strings can be funny with spaces.

```
Dim sCommand = """pushd \\*\C$ && whoami.exe >> C:\JavaInfo.txt && java.exe -version 2>> C:\JavaInfo.txt"""
```

Comment: Bingo. The double quotes mentioned sent things all over the place. But something somewhere along the way of setting to true and no timeout made it click. Now I get understandable output in the text file and Window.

Comment: Have a look at String.Format too for formatting strings instead of using replace.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Comment: @harper89. Thats exactly what I have mentioned.adding wait to shell command.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because javainfo.txt ia already in use.

To confirm the same just add * to file name. e.g. javainfo*.txt

If its confirmed remove * from file name and set wait= true in shell function and your code will work

Comment: Adding * to the javainfo.txt would make a text file for each and every domain user? I would like them all in one and be able to just have it write a duplicate in the same file if needed.

Comment: As I mentioned once it is confirmed files are created you can remove the *
Step 1 confirm files are getting created by adding *. Step 2 remove * and set wait parameter of shell command to true.